# MongoDB as the primary database?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have read a lot of the MongoDB.

I like all the features it provides, but I wonder if it's possible to have it as the only database for my application, including storing sensitive information.

I know that it compromises the durability part in ACID but I will as a solution have 1 master and 2 slaves in different locations.

If I do that, is it possible to use it as the primary database, storing everything?

UPDATE:

Lets put it this way.

I really need a document storage rather than traditional dbms for be able to create my flexible application. But is MongoDB reliable enough to store customer sensitive information if I have multiple database replications and master-slave? Cause as far as I know one major downside is that it compromises the D in ACID. So I solve it with multiple databases.

Now there is not major problems such as lost of data issues?

And someone told me that with MongoDB a customer could be billed twice. Could someone enlighten this?

Comment: Why do you want or need to use MongoDB? What are the benefits as you see them? Why is say, postgres not a right fit for your application? Some companies (friendfeed) simply store JSON in a RDBMS, giving a flexible schema with the ACID benefits of a normal DB.

Comment: You can also use CouchDB, it is also a document db.

Comment: @Mark. Cause I prefer working with objects and objects embedded in objects rather than tables, columns and rows. I like OOP paradigm more cause it fits the way of human thinking. XML/JSON datatypes can't replace that. It's just for storing small structures not the whole database structure.

Comment: @TTT. I know that this is not a drawback of CouchDB but for me it's very cumbersome to have to think about the views for every query I want to perform and no predefined view was there. Why I prefer NOSQL is because it helps me to think in a way that is very human-friendly, so even though views are good for computers it doesn't fit my way of thinking. I just don't believe in the same vision I guess. I want OOP even at the query side and MongoDB gives me that.

Comment: Simply adding more databases/slaves doesn't give you ACID properties in mongodb, you will have to work a lot harder to get consistency when you add another db.(e.g. what happens if you update the master and calculate stuff on the slave, but the slave havn't seen the update, what happens if you calculate stuff on a 2. connection ,but you've given only "read your own writes" consistency, and not transactions as traditional rdvms give you ?)

Comment: MongoDB is in no way an object database. In fact, I'm surprised you so quickly dismiss CouchDB--they have more in common than not. Internally, MongoDB actually stores everything as BSON, which is just a binary representation of JSON. This does free you from having to define a schema (so if that's what you need, go for it), but other than that, almost everything you can do in MongoDB you can also do with a relational database. Given the proper level of abstraction on the software side, you shouldn't even have to think about what kind of database you're dealing with.

Comment: Anyway, I still think more info about your specific application would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, MongoDB can work as an application's only data store.  Use replication and make sure you know about [safe writes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Last+Error+Commands) and [w](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Verifying+Propagation+of+Writes+with+getLastError).

> And someone told me that with MongoDB a customer could be billed 
>   twice. Could someone enlighten this?

I'm guessing whoever told you that was talking about eventual consistency.  Some NoSQL databases are eventually consistent, meaning that you could have conflicting writes.  MongoDB is not, though, it is strongly consistent (just like a relational database).

Comment: I have a hard time understanding safe writes. What is the difference between fsync() and getLastError()?

Comment: safe writes return whether the write succeeded (the db was up, you didn't try to insert a non-unique value into a unique field, etc.).  fsync actually makes sure that change is written to disk, not just present in memory.  See http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1052759609/mongodb-safe-and-fsync-explained.

Answer (score 7):

Your application being flexible or not has absoutely nothing to do with wether you use "nosql", a "document db" or a proper RDBMS. Nobody using your application will care either way.

If you need flexibility while coding, you should research into frameworks, like ActiveRecord for Ruby, which can make DB-interfacing much more simple, generic and powerful. At that level, you can gain alot more than just changing the DB, and you can even become DB-agnostic, meaning you can change DB without changing *any* code. Indeed, I have found ActiveRecord to boost my productivity many many fold by alleviating me from tedious and error-prone "code intermixed with SQL".

Indeed, if you feel you need a schemaless database, for critical data, you are doing something wrong. You are putting your own convenience over critical needs of the projects, or in ignorance thinking you won't get into problems later. Sooner or later, lack of consistency will bite your ass, hard!

I feel you are hesistant towards RDBMS because you are not really that comfortable with all the jargons, syntax and sound CS principles.

Believe me, if you're going to create an application of any value, you are hundred times better learning SQL, ACID and good database-principles in the first place. Just read up on the basics, and build your knowledge from wherever you are now. It's the same for each and every one of us, it takes time, but you learn to do things right from the start.

Low-level tools like MongoDB and equivalent just provide you with infinitely more ammunition to shoot yourself in the foot with. They make it seem easy. In reality however, they leave the hard work for you, the coder, to deal with, while an RDBMS will handle more of the cruft for you once you grok the basics.

Why use computers at all, if you want more work, you can just go back to paper. Design will be a breeze, and implementation can be super-quick. Done. Except it won't be right of course.

In the real world, we can't afford to ignore consistency, database design and many more sound CS principles. Which is why it's a great idea to study them in the first place, and keep learning more and more.

Don't buy into the hype. You ask question about MongoDB here, but include that you really *need* its features. With 25 years of computer experience, I simply don't buy it. If you think creatively, an RDBMS can be made to do whatever you want it to, or a framework can be utilized to save you from errors and wasted time.

Crafting ACID properties onto MongoDB seems like more work to me, and by experience, sounds like an excercise in futility, rather than using what is already designed to suit such purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible? Sure. Why not? It's possible to store everything as XML in text files if you wanted to.

Is it the best idea? It depends on what you're trying to do, the rest of your system architecture, the scale your site is intended to achieve, and so on.